# Assign something to a "user"?

Tags: trello

Trello is wonderful for keeping and organizing tasks and users, but there are times when a task isn't assigned to someone on my team, or even someone who's heard of Trello.

Is there a way (short of creating an entire fake email address/account) to have some kind of "external user"?  That way, it can be seen at a glance that a card is assigned (maybe to some kind of DevOps ticket waiting on tech support from your vendor) without that person needing to be part of your Trello board/team.